# Render value without quotes from simple-json Object

Tags: json, jakarta-ee

I try to do in a Servlet:

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
json.put( "eventContent", "event" );
String script = "var object= " + json.toJSONString() + ";";
response.getWriter().print( something + script + another );
```

The content of script is of course:

```
var object = {"eventContent":"event"};
```

But I render this String into a javascript function and try to refer a existent javascript object "event". So I need the value in the JSON Sting without quotes.

```
var object = {"eventContent":event};
```

any suggestions? :)

thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's not really JSON, since you should not refer variables. Anyway you can obtain what you need by implementing the `JSONString` interface, like this.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws JSONException {
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
    json.put( "eventContent", new JSONVariable("event") );
    System.out.println("var object= " + json.toString() + ";");
}

private static class JSONVariable implements JSONString { // implements JSONAware with com.googlecode.json-simple
    private final String name;

    public JSONVariable(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toJSONString() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

Comment: I use the "com.googlecode.json-simple" maven artifact(Ver. 1.1.1) and can't find a JSONString Interface. Which lib did you mean?

Comment: I was using the files found in www.json.org. Try with `implements JSONAware`?